# Where to release an object? dealloc or ViewDidUNload

Tags: iphone, memory, memory-management

When we need to release an object,where to do it, either at the dealloc method or in the ViewDidUnload for a viewController? which would be better?

I think that viewDidUnload would do better, because once the view controller is unloaded the objects would be released. And in the dealloc case, from the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000043-SW6)

> When an application terminates,
>   objects may not be sent a dealloc
>   message. Because the process’s memory
>   is automatically cleared on exit, it
>   is more efficient simply to allow the
>   operating system to clean up resources
>   than to invoke all the memory
>   management methods.

the objects may not be sent a dealloc message upon the Application quitting.

So I find it would be better if objects got released earlier, than postponing their release thereby reducing the memory footprint the Application takes.

If my understanding is wrong, please correct me.

Thanks and Regards,
Krishnan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, your understanding is wrong.

First, it doesn't matter what happens when the application quits because the OS will free all the memory that your app allocated anyway. Not calling dealloc on app termination is just Apple's way to speed this up.

Second, it is not the view *controller* that is unloaded when `viewDidUnload` is called but only its *view*. The view controller stays alive until it is deallocated.

In `viewDidUnload`, you have to release those objects that are part of the view and everything that can and will be recreated in `viewDidLoad` (because `viewDidLoad` will be called again when the view controller need to recreate its view). This includes all your outlets. You also have to set these variables to `nil` to avoid overreleasing them.

Because in `dealloc`, you should release all objects your view controller retains, including those you included in `viewDidUnload`.

Have a look at any of Apple's sample code to see how Apple does this.

Comment: Hi Ole, Thanks for the response.Now I understand that, I should release in ViewDidUnload, what ever I have created in ViewDIdLoad.

One doubt, I have is that should I release something in -dealloc method that  already I have released in -ViewDidUnload method. Because When my -dealloc is to  be called, the view should be removed and the -viewDidUnload must have been called. So I guess it would be a duplication of code.

Please share your thoughts. Thanks 

Regards,
krishnan.

Comment: Apple has this duplicate release pattern in all their sample code so I suggest you follow their example. It is not entirely clear from the documentation whether `viewDidUnload` is always called before `dealloc`. It is important to also set the variables to `nil` in `viewDidUnload` to avoid over-releasing objects.

Comment: This just may add a little -- from experience viewDidUnload is rarely called.  In fact, it is only called when the app experiences a low memory scenario, from the apple docs on viewDidUnload.  If you want to be sure you've freed up memory, then dealloc is the place to do it.  Duplication shouldn't matter -- you can send messages (like release) to nil without a problem.  But make sure you nil out your variables otherwise you'll be sending messages to a random chunk of memory possibly!

Answer (score 1):

You have to take in consideration that from iOS 6

> viewDidUnload

is NEVER called, as from Apple:

> Prior to iOS 6, when a low-memory warning occurred, the
>   UIViewController class purged its views if it knew it could reload or
>   recreate them again later. If this happens, it also calls the
>   viewWillUnload and viewDidUnload methods to give your code a chance to
>   relinquish ownership of any objects that are associated with your view
>   hierarchy, including objects loaded from the nib file, objects created
>   in your viewDidLoad method, and objects created lazily at runtime and
>   added to the view hierarchy. On iOS 6, views are never purged and
>   these methods are never called. If your view controller needs to
>   perform specific tasks when memory is low, it should override the
>   didReceiveMemoryWarning method.